# is there simple way to integrate vuejs to a existing project folder?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to find a simple way to integrate vuejs to an existing project folder. I created a simple app which only contents few basic files. Now I'd like to use this small project to learn more about vuejs. Since most tutorials were about using VueJS from a standpoint of building a new site. I'm wondering How to integrate vuejs to an existing project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Component registration is different when using a webpack based project (I'm not sure if webpack is the cause I think so though) and implementing Vue into a single page in your multiple page web app. To use Vue the way you want, use the CDN and follow [this guide](https://medium.com/@disjfa/using-vue-js-in-existing-websites-the-easy-way-d46cd1f0c945)
Otherwise, manual component registration isn't necessary in Vue CLI-3 it's done automatically in the javascript section of each single file component using the export:

```js
export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
  // rest of the component
}
```

Single-Use of Vue (Local Registration):

```js
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data(): {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p>{{message}}</p>
    </div>


 <script>
        var demo = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
            }
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks James. export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
  // rest of the component
}I was n't looking for a CDN solution.

Comment: thanks again James.  Vue. CLI is what I was after
I will try
 export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
}
BTW, I should of clarify that I was n't looking for a CDN solution. Given I have tried it before. It  surely is  an easy way to integrate to a small project  :) cheers

Comment: Yea ofc bro gl!